# return subset of object from a object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
{'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'b': ['b1', 'b2'], 'c': [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

How can i write a function to only return subset of object? I have following but is there a better way to do it?

```
function exportObject(obj: Record<string, Array<string>>, key: string){
  return {key: obj[key]}
}
```

Comment: That looks quite short and reasonable to me (except that `Array<string>` is the wrong type), what sort of improvements were you thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[key]` as property:

```js
function exportObject(obj: Record<string, Array<string|number>>, key: string){
  return {[key]: obj[key]}
}
```

you also missed the `number` in `Array<string|number>>`.